# jQuery adds sub-menu dropdown symbol INSIDE parent <a> tag. How can I add it OUTSIDE?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

As an example, check out nycfitclub.com

In the mobile menu, if you click the parent item's text, it acts like a link. If you click the symbol itself, it toggles the submenu without activating the parent link. I'm trying to achieve this on my own website [here](http://phpstack-77308-296444.cloudwaysapps.com/) without using Bootstrap.

This is a Wordpress site, so I add my menu with some basic php:

```
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_class' => 'jd-main-nav', 'container' => 'nav'));?>
```

This gives me some classes to play with, notably **.sub-menu** and **.menu-item-has-children** - I'm trying to target those with jQuery.

My first attempt is positioned correctly (inline next to the parent item) but jQuery is adding it INSIDE the link. So when you click the symbol, it correctly toggles, but it also acts like a normal link click:

```
     $('.sub-menu').prevUntil('.menu-item-has-children').append('<span class="jd-nav-arrow">&#9660</span>');
```

My second attempt toggles correctly but unfortunately, jQuery is adding the symbol BELOW the parent link... which is ugly:

```
     $('.menu-item-has-children').append('<span class="jd-nav-arrow">&#9660</span>');
```

Ideally, the submenu symbol sits inline next to the parent (like option 1) but DOES NOT activate the parent link (like option 2) - how can I achieve this? I've included an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCyEL.png). Please note this is for mobile screens, so you'll want to shrink your screen down inside 768px.

*P.S. This is my first post. I tried to find this exact solution for over an hour, so please forgive me if this has already been answered.*

Comment: This is a very well written question, but it would be quite helpful to start by stating what you're trying to do before going on to explain what you did and the output you got.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to be quite clear - I've reworded and hopefully it's better. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Using option 2, try giving `.jd-main-nav > ul > li > a` a `display: inline-block` so the symbol in span sits next to it, and to make sure menu items are stacked on top of one another you can give `.jd-main-nav > ul >  li` a `display: block`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Incredible - it works! Thank you so much! May I ask you for one more detail?

If you go back to my URL [here](http://phpstack-77308-296444.cloudwaysapps.com/) you'll see I added a second submenu. Clicking either sub-menu's dropdown will toggle **both** submenus... how can I specify the jQuery to toggle the single, correct submenu?

My toggle code is as follows:     `$(".jd-nav-arrow").click(function(){  $(".sub-menu").toggle(0, function(){     });  });`

Should've thought about this earlier, so my apologies & thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind, solved! Just replaced `$(".sub-menu")` with `$(this).siblings(".sub-menu")` - thank you so much again for your initial help, @Sheedo

Comment: Glad I could help! Sorry, it was quite late where I live couldn't help with the second problem, but well done solving it on you own!

Comment: Glad you got sorted! Now that you have a solution, I suggest that you or @Sheedo add it as an answer in keeping with the Q&A format of the site, so that anyone else with similar issues will find it.

Comment: Good suggestion @FluffyKitten, I've added the answer John, feel free to improve on it and confirm it's the correct answer for others to benefit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using option 2, you can give `.jd-main-nav > ul > li > a` a property of `display: inline-block` so the symbol in span sits next to it. 
To make sure menu items are stacked on top of one another you can set the `display` of `.jd-main-nav > ul > li` to be `block`. This will look as follows in your `style.css`:

```
.jd-main-nav > ul > li > a {
display: inline-block; /* this allows symbols to be next to menu items */ 
}
.jd-main-nav > ul > li {
display: block; /* this ensures menu items sit on top of one another */
}
```

You can then use jQuery to toggle the submenus like so:

```
 $(".jd-nav-arrow").click(function(){ $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").toggle(0, function(){ }); });
```

Comment: You guys have been extremely helpful. I was hesitant to post my first question, but it couldn't have gone better. I was also unsure how to check your answer as correct - glad to have the clarity! Thanks again!